# Fun educational book about English language with a wide spectrum of knowledge and facts

Tags: discussion

I am looking for a fun educational book about English language with a wide spectrum of knowledge and facts. I did some research but there are too many books and too many directions, I cannot read them all. I hope there might be some folks on this forum who already read some gems, or heard of some bestsellers. I am ESL person, but you can ignore that. Many native speakers as I understand could benefit from a great book telling them about the language they speak. I expect something that is humorous, captivating, instructive, knowledgable, useful, educational, encompassing things from grammar to style, from punctuation to perhaps some history, from fine details to bird-eye-views - just a word cloud of descriptive things. I bet such book would be a bestseller, because it would be just popular among many types of readers. A cool book about some deeper sense of English language for those who wish to learn and have different backgrounds. A book to satisfy many tastes and inspire many minds. I came by an example:

- Dreyer’s English: An Utterly Correct Guide to Clarity and Style
- by Benjamin Dreyer
- https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/40063024

. . . but honestly - this might be too hard for some ESL folks - I mean his extremely witty references that only seasoned native speaker can get. Any other ideas of perhaps some classics for broader audience?

Thank you!

Comment: Your question belongs on the Meta part of this site. For example, here you will find a comprehensive list of resources: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/what-are-your-favorite-english-language-tools . My recommendation is David Crystal's _The English Language_. It is not necessarily humurous, but it has all the other qualities you are asking for:   https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/901145.The_Cambridge_Encyclopedia_of_the_English_Language?from_search=true&qid=EdjtqG35ge&rank=2

Comment: @Shoe thank you ! you said the book's name is "The English Language" but then pointed to "The Cambridge Encyclopedia of the English Language" -- did you mean this is the same thing?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the unnecessary confusion!

Comment: I quite like '*Eats, Shoots and Leaves: The Zero Tolerance Approach to Punctuation by Lynne Truss*' for a humourous (and serious) look at punctuation.

Comment: You say (1) "*I am ESL person, but you can ignore that*" and (2) "*I came by an example: . . . but honestly - this might be too hard for some ESL folks.*" So, which is it? Is ESL a factor or not?

Comment: @Smock Lynne is quite prescriptive - it's a good read though!

Comment: Let me second @Shoe's recommendation. First, anything by David Crystal is good stuff, and there's quite a lot of it, all about language in some way. Second, his encyclopedias for Cambridge University Press are especially good.  [_The Cambridge Encyclopedia of Language_](https://www.amazon.com/Cambridge-Encyclopedia-Language-David-Crystal/dp/0521736501/ref=asc_df_0521736501/) and [_The Cambridge Encyclopedia of the English Language_](https://www.amazon.com/Cambridge-Encyclopedia-English-Language/dp/1108437737/ref=asc_df_1108437737) should be in every Anglophone classroom, worldwide.

Comment: Oh, and Truss is totally innocent of any knowledge about [punctuation](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/IELL-Punctuation.pdf). She goes in the same bin as [Strunk and White](http://www.todroberts.com/USF/50_Years_of_Stupid_Grammar_Advice.com.pdf).